# Ought we keep our [legal] tag?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Medical Sciences Stack Exchange post: [How can Plaintiff get a compounded medication tested, to determine if it was negligently compounded?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/32264/how-can-plaintiff-get-a-compounded-medication-tested-to-determine-if-it-was-neg)

I'm aware of Law Stack Exchange, but we ought keep [legal](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal), because some [medico-legal questions](https://www.medico-legalsociety.org.uk) require medical knowledge.

[Jiminy Cricket.](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/32264/how-can-plaintiff-get-a-compounded-medication-tested-to-determine-if-it-was-neg#comment62651_32264) tipped me to ask about the [legal](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) tag here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags are labels to help people find questions they are interested in. They are especially important on higher traffic sites like Stack Overflow because there are *so many* questions posted there that it's important for users to be able to filter to only the topics they are interested in.

Tags do **not** determine what is on- or off-topic. The existence or non-existence of the tag [legal](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) does not affect whether a question using that tag is allowed or should be closed.

Your question was closed because it is not about Medical Sciences.